# Как в number_format() вместо запятых сделать точки в цифрах?

Tags: php

Имеется переменная с балансом человека, хотелось бы спросить, как вместо запятых в функции `number_format()` сделать точки, допустим вместо `1,000` – `1.000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтение [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) рулит:

```
number_format($number, 0, '.', '');
```

Comment: Заменить 2 на 0.